# Why does attempting to return in this function cause the program to crash in C++?

Tags: c++

I am working through challenges on a site called CodeFights to help me learn C++ and improve my programming. One challenge was to write a program that would find the length of a specific sequence based on the zeroth element:

Element 0: 16

Element 1: 1^2 + 6^2 = 37

Element 2: 3^2 + 7^2 = 58

...

The sequence ends when an element is repeated.

This code is supposed to return the length of the sequence:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int squareDigitsSequence(int a0) {
    int counter = 0; //Counts number of elements
    int temp = 0; //Stores current element
    std::vector<int> sequence (1); //Stores sequence
    sequence[0] = a0; //Stores first element in sequence
    for (int i = 0;; i++) { //Loops until sequence finishes
        counter += 1; //Increments counter
        temp = 0; //Resets element storage
        if (a0 < 10) { //If it is only 1 digit
            temp += pow(a0, 2);
        }
        else if (a0 < 100 && a0 > 9) { //If it is 2 digits
            temp += pow(a0 / 10, 2);
            temp += pow(a0 % 10, 2);
        }
        else { //If it is 3 digits
            temp += pow(a0 % 10, 2);
            temp += pow(((a0 % 100) - (a0 % 10)) / 10, 2);
            temp += pow(a0 / 100, 2);
        }
        for (int b = 0; b < counter; b++) { //Checks if the element has appeared before
            if (temp == sequence[b]) {
                return counter; //Crashes here.
            }
        }
        sequence[i + 1] = temp; //Stores current element in sequence
        a0 = temp; //Moves element to be checked to current element
    }
    return 0; //Would not accept the function without this
}

int main() {
    std::cout << squareDigitsSequence(16);
    return 0;
}
```

Attempting to run this causes the program to crash. I have attempted to debug, and also look for similar problems but no success. Help appreciated.

EDIT: The problem was that I created a vector with size (1), and tried to add more elements to it. Solution use .push_back() instead of [i + 1].

Thanks to everyone that answered, hope this can be useful to others in the future.

Comment: You program probably _crashes_ here `if (temp == sequence[b]) {`, not at the return. Check all the indices used in your debugger thoroughly.

Comment: Can you elaborate on / clarify the input and expected output please.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: The coding question has already been answered. But it's a mystery to me what the sequence is. It looks like 16 + k*21, but the examples have some sums of squares. What is it? And what is the "length"?

Comment: Thanks @eran, and everyone who has replied, using push_back now makes the program run correctly. It does not give the correct answer, but that's something I can solve myself.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The sequence is the sum of the square of each digit in the previous element. It just happens that it incremented by 21 for the first few. The "length" of the sequence is how many elements are there before it repeats.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I had previously checked, and confirmed it crashed at the return. Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: besides, you should not use pow for squares, or for integers.  pow(x,y) is calculated as `exp(y * log(x))`, which is (1) not precise (2) slow.  Instead define an inline function `sq(x)` which calculates `x*x`.  Make it template if you can.

Comment: Maybe at some point you need to push_back to your sequence? or resize()???

Comment: @DanielA.Thompson The input can be found in main(), the first element is 16. The expected output is 9 (the length before it repeats itself). The main issue was the crashing, and this has been resolved, but thanks for your support.

Comment: @user31264 Thanks for this, did not know about sq(x). Will use it in future programs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crash is the result of an out-of-bound write in this line:

```
sequence[i + 1] = temp;
```

Since the vector is initialized with size 1 and never resized, you overflow the internal buffer and override some arbitrary memory location.

To avoid this problem, use `vector::push_back`, which will enlarge the vector if the internal buffer isn't large enough.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, have been working on this one for hours!

Comment: You're welcome. And btw, the crash is a good outcome. It is probably the result of the deletion of the vector's buffer when the vector went out of scope. During the delete, the memory manager may detect the override and throw. Had it not, the program would have continued with a corrupted state, and tracing the corruption back to its origin would have been way more difficult.